# Bootstrap 4 carousel Iframe no-gutters

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a two column layout with heading and P to the left of a bootstrap carousel with numerous Iframe videos. I am trying to get the iframe carousel to fit the entire space of its block. I have tried adding no-gutters but cannot find a solution. I'm wondering if this is even possible since the Iframe has set dimensions 16by9.

```
 <div class="container-fluid p-5 back-test text-light testimonials">
<div class="row justify-content-lg-between text-center">
  <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12 align-self-center ml-lg-4 pr-2 pb-sm-3">
    <h1>We're With <span class="you">You</span><br><span class="extra">We Go The Extra Mile</span></h1>
    <p>At Here are a few notable testimonials that we would like to share with you.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
      <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-1IHHJmuc78" class="vid-one" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                   <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-1IHHJmuc78" class="vid-one" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zTiSxfCarPM" class="vid-one" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                     </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you hoping to do this just using bootstrap classes or using CSS?

Comment: Either solution would be fine....I could add media queries if it does not look right on smaller screen sizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Apply `.no-gutters` to your `.row`.
2. Drop the `.container-fluid` wrapper. See [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#no-gutters) (the bold "*Need an edge-to-edge design?*")
3. Drop all `p{side}-{size}` and `m{side}-{size}`classes. They apply `margin`s and `padding`s with `!important`. You really don't want that.

Result:

```css
/* demo purposes */
body:not(#_) {background-color: #888;}
.row {background-color: white;}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row justify-content-lg-between text-center no-gutters">
  <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12 align-self-center">
    <h1>We're With <span class="you">You</span><br><span class="extra">We Go The Extra Mile</span></h1>
    <p>At Here are a few notable testimonials that we would like to share with you.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
      <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-1IHHJmuc78" class="vid-one" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                   <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-1IHHJmuc78" class="vid-one" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zTiSxfCarPM" class="vid-one" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                     </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
  </div>
```